# visual studio c# windows form checkBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, checkbox, fonts

I need your help
as you can see from the screenshot image 
I am trying to make a font dialog where i have:
a Label to test the change that will happen when I
click in the checkbox .as you can see I have 3 checkboxs.
the problem is that **I cant make all the checkboxs work together** 
so the text changed to Bold,Italic and underline..help me please
.....

[my Form design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTvSu.png)

i try to use if else statement
and also switch one and still I don't know how to do it that is why i m here

Comment: Show some code, and tell us as precisely as possible what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: well there is no magic here..and we all forgot to wear out `Mind Reading` hats this Friday.. so you will need to show some code and please show a little more effort and show us what you have tried..

Comment: this up to you someone might understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit unclear, as others have noted, but.. if you are  wanting to combine the results of checked and/or unchecked options to display the results of a user's font styling choices?

THEN:

1.) double-click in your V.S. form designer one of the checkboxes, this will create an event handler in your form's C# code file. The function created will be something like `checkbox1_checked(object sender, EventArgs e)`

2.) In the event handler function that Visual Studio has scaffolded for you, write all the code necessary to consider the `.Checked` state of all checkbox controls and update your `Label1` control appropriately (depending on your goal, this may require custom .NET painting logic that is too much for a beginner to think about)

3.) Go back to the other controls on your design surface, now select them.. keeping an eye on your lower-right 'Properties' panel, (make sure its switched to the 'events' tab - i.e. click the 'lightning bolt' button). Ensure that each of the other radio buttons that do not yet have an event handler get mapped: Find the row in the Properties panel that shows the word "click" (err.. 'checked' event?). When you click into the white space on the row, next to the word 'checked', it will allow you to select the pre-existing "checkbox1_checked" event handler than you created in step 1.

UPDATED:

4.) the end goal is to wire all checkbox controls to the same event handler function in your form's code-behind.. if you double-click each checkbox at design time.. you'll create separate event handlers.. but with some learning (or following my directions above) you can point them all to the same event handler.